# Isotope item height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

In a Bootstrap based website I have a page with a gallery managed by the Isotope plugin, each item in the gallery has some text of a different length.

The gallery container contains a #grid-sizer item that takes advantage of the Bootstrap grid classes:

```
<div id="gallery_container" class="row">
  <div id="grid-sizer" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
  <div class="photo">
    <div class="peu-producte">
      <div class="text-peu">
        Some text
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So each column gets sized by a percentage suitable also for small displays.

This is how Isotope is initialized:

```
    var $container = $('#gallery_container');

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.photo',

        masonry: {
           columnWidth: '#grid-sizer'
        }
    });
```

The problem is: when the text inside `.text-peu` is longer than one line, the `.photo` item next to it is skipped, as if Isotope assumed a wider `.photo` div.

I've experienced that if I break the text with `<br>`tags, then the calculation is correct.

Comment: Please add a sample showing your problem on codepen or jsfiddle for us to check out.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `.photo` div width before initializing Isotope solved the problem!